# How to synchronize / mirror the 'Files' Repository and the 'git' Repository in SourceForge?

Tags: git, file, sourceforge

we are at the moment building a community utilities repository in sourceforge which will be managed by several 'managers' but accessible to the community.
I have initially uploaded all the utilities into the 'Files' tab of the project. After this, I could see that git could also be used which seems handy for us.

So have created the project Repository in git/SourceForge and pushed the entire project, which is fine.

The question is that I have a strong feeling that the files listed in the sourceforge 'Files' tab are totally distinct from files I can see in the 'Git' tab.

We would like to manage the files from git, but have the files visible and available from the 'Files' tab.

Is this possible? I have a feeling that the files in the 'Files' tab are stored in a different place than the files in the 'Git' tab.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are in completely different places at SF and you cannot synchronize them automatically. One of the reasons you cannot synchronize git and files is that git repositories at SF are bare, they don't contain working directory, they only contain object database and references.

Do you know you can use [`ssh`](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/SSH/) to login to SF, [`scp`](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/SCP/), [`sftp`](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/SFTP/) and [`rsync`](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/rsync/) to transfer files to and from? I use it all the times since 2004.

To login to your account run

```
ssh -t $SF_USER@shell.sourceforge.net create
```

After login run `sf-help --all` to see all your directories.

Files, repositories and web-files (do you know you can publish a site at SF?) are in project-specific paths. For example I'm a member of [SQLObject](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlobject/) project, my user name at SF is `phd`. The repositories for the project are at `/home/git/p/sqlobject/`, files are at `/home/frs/project/sqlobject/` and web-files (published at [SQLObject](http://sqlobject.org/)) are at `/home/project-web/sqlobject/`. These are just an example but your directories are similar.

To upload file I use `sftp frs.sourceforge.net:/home/frs/project/sqlobject` and upload local files to SF.

To update web site I run

```
rsync -hlrtP4 --del . web.sourceforge.net:/home/project-web/sqlobject/htdocs/
```

Replace `sqlobject` with the name of your project and start uploading.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Now I understand how it works. Given that I can have a ssh on the sourceforge server, I bet the File tab can be fed by a git clone to the sourceforge git repository, which in that case would work perfect for me. Just need to git pull everytime there is a push from one of the repository admins

Comment: Well, this does not work: permissions are not sufficient to create a .git repository. I'll try with rsync

Comment: It could be that FRS and web don't allow files with names starting with a dot. `rsync --exclude=.git/`